# How to get objects which have an object in their ManyToManyField?

Tags: django, django-models

There's this model:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, related_name='followings', null=True, blank=True)
```

Say I have a user object called 'A'. In a view, I want to filter User objects which have 'A' as their follower. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query with:

```
A.followings.all()
```

The [**`related_name=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) is the name of the relation in reverse, so it is a `QuerySet` of `User`s that have `A` as `follower`.

If you do not specify a `related_name=…` it will take the name of the model in lowercase followed by the `…_set` suffix, so `user_set` in this case.

If you only have the primary key of `A`, then you can query with:

```
User.objects.filter(followers__id=a_id)
```

---

> **Note**: Using [**`null=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.null) for a [**`ManyToManyField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) makes no sense: one can not enforce by the database that a `ManyToManyField` should be non-empty, therefore as the documentation says: "*`null` has no effect since there is no way to require a relationship at the database level.*"